# Linux making shortcut of a compiled code

Tags: linux, shortcut

I am trying to make a shortcut of an executable on the background of the linux system. I would like to execute it when I double-click the icon on the background. The only way I know how to run a code is using xterm and type `./program`

I would greatly appreciate if someone can tell me how to do so. Thank you

Comment: Which desktop? "Linux" itself is a kernel, no GUI or desktop. There are many desktop environments out there, the answer depends on which one you are using.

Comment: It actually could depend on the actual desktop you are using.

Comment: You don't *run C++ code*, you run a program (executable file) you previously compiled *from* C++ code. So actually this doesn't have anything to do with C++.

Comment: Are you using GNOME, KDE, XFCE...?

Comment: I am using GNOME and I'm using angstrom linux distribution.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using gnome (or desktop environments which support the following), you can just create a `myprogram.desktop` file. (This is somewhat similar to .lnk files in Windows.) It contains a command to be executed and you can give it a meaningful name (which is not the filename).

An example might look like the following.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=My Program
Exec=/home/foo/bar/myprogram
Type=Application
```

Save this file on your desktop and give it execution permissions (`chmod +x myprogram.desktop`).

Here, I used the absolute file name to link the executable file, so it will be found regardless your current working directory.

If your program uses the standard output to display important information, you can tell the desktop environment to run the command within a terminal window by adding

```
Terminal=true
```

You can also specify an icon with

```
Icon=/home/foo/bar/myprogram.png
```

The documentation can be found [here](http://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/ar01s05.html).